# Check if Startup Folder already contains program

Tags: c#

I basically want to check if the current program is already linked to Windows Startup Folder, even if the file has another name or is ran from another directory. Is this possible, maybe by checking the program's name?

PS: I use this code to link my program to the Startup folder:

```
using (ShellLink shortcut = new ShellLink()) {
    shortcut.Target = Application.ExecutablePath;
    shortcut.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
    shortcut.Description = "My Shorcut Name Here";
    shortcut.DisplayMode = ShellLink.LinkDisplayMode.edmNormal;
    shortcut.Save(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Startup));
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to scan startup's start menu folder, and for each shortcut compare the target path with your program's path.

```
WshShell shell = new WshShell(); 
var link = (IWshShortcut)shell.CreateShortcut(linkPathName); //Link the interface to our shortcut
var target = link.TargetPath;
//compare to your program's path...
```

Comment: Isn't it possible that the Application can ran from any location, as I wrote above? So it shouldn't check the path, it should check the program's name / ID (if something like that exists).

Comment: Then you have to get the program's path at runtime, with this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.startuppath.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Trying out to write a trojan? =D

Straightforward solution: enumerate all shortcuts (lnk-files) in the Startup folder, open them all 1 by 1 and see (I assume you are using [this](http://www.vbaccelerator.com/home/NET/Code/Libraries/Shell_Projects/Creating_and_Modifying_Shortcuts/article.asp) technique).

Comment: I am not writing a trojan ;). Check out my comment at CharlesB's post.